# How to emulate erf and/or the Normal Inverse function in Moodle?

Tags: probability, moodle, normal-distribution

[This question was originally posted [on Math Education SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/17537/12754), but I'm not sure what place is the best. You can still have a look at it for MathJax readability.]

I've just discovered "calculated questions" in Moodle and I'm trying to create a simple one where I would be asking the student to find the probability that an observation from a standard normal population be greater than variable {z}.

I then define the range of {z} as [-3,3] with 2 decimal places.

Now since Moodle doesn't have erf implemented I have been trying to emulate it using Jack D'Aurizio's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1172532), and otherwise Abramowitz and Stegun's first approximation given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Approximation_with_elementary_functions), which results in $$P(z_i> z)\approx \frac{1-\sqrt{1-e^{-0.619495805z^2}}}2$$ for the former, for instance (leaving this in MathJax to save you some time if you have a MathJax reader at hand).

I am facing the problem that **Moodle refuses to calculate this when z is less than 2** (I get the output ***NaN***) and as for the values where it will output something, **the outputs don't seem to depend much on z**, I get only four different possible outputs which are 0, 0.005, 0.035 and 0.102.

Two examples copy-pasted from Moodle:

`1-(1+sqrt(1-exp(-0.619495805*((40.14-11.7)/4.3)^2)))/2 = 0.035`

`1-(1+sqrt(1-exp(-0.619495805*((33.18-13)/4.1)^2)))/2 = 0.102`

Where here z was actually calculated via z=(x-m)/s.

Does anyone know how to work around this and get actual proper values for the normal inverse function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found by @user1527 on Math Education SE: the problem comes from using `^` for powers. That's not the correct Moodle syntax, it should be `pow(number, exponent)`. Fixing this fixed everything.

It still doesn't explain why Moodle did calculate something in some cases though, it might be a bug in Moodle.